# MongoDB é mais rápido que bancos de dados SQL?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, mongodb, desempenho, nosql

Vejo diversas afirmações que usar um NoSQL, como o MongoDB, é mais rápido que usar um banco de dados relacional. É verdade? Como isso se dá? Qual é a mágica?

Comment: E o Redis? É mais rápido que bancos de dados SQL?

Comment: Meio que está na resposta, Redis é cache. Até pode ser classificado com DB, mas de forma muito específica, ninguém usa ele no lugar do MongoDB ou de um relacional, usa como complemento ou em um cenário bem específico. Aí pode ser muito rápido, só que não faz a mesma coisa. Se acessar ele no mesmo padrão que acessa em um DB relacional, mudando a consulta, fica tragicamente lento.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É verdade sob certas condições. O oposto também é verdade.

Ao contrário da crença popular (de alguns), bancos de dados NoSQL, em especial o MongoDB que é o mais adotado indiscriminadamente, que recebe muito *marketing* para vender a ideia que é mais rápido, não fazem milagres, não tem mágica, eles não descobriram algo que ninguém mais é capaz de fazer mesmo vendo o código fonte deles. É até ingenuidade muito grande acreditar nisso.

Toda tecnologia fará escolhas, os chamados *tradeoffs*, então é normal que em alguns casos ela consiga um resultado melhor que outra tecnologia que optou por uma forma diferente de fazer.

O caso mais óbvio que faz as pessoas mostrarem isso é usando o modelo de documento no MongoDB e um modelo relacional no SQL. Está comparando bananas com parafusos.

Experimenta fazer o mesmo modelo relacional, que dá, no MongoDB e compare a performance.

Alguém já está apressado dizendo que não é para fazer isso. E não é mesmo, mas esse é o ponto: **não dá para comparar coisas tão diferentes**. Mas para comparar de forma justa tem que fazer, e aí vemos que não tem milagre.

Ok, quer fazer o oposto? Monte no banco de dados SQL todo desnormalizado (que é o que o MongoDB manda você fazer), ou seja, armazene como documentos, que dá, e diga qual é mais rápido.

Se você **abrir mão das garantias e facilidades**, além da organização que o modelo relacional oferece, então não tem motivos para qualquer banco de dados ser mais lento que o MongoDB ou outro concorrente NoSQL. E se achar diferenças fundamentais, alguma coisa não está otimizada de forma correta para alcançar bom resultado.

Se você forçar *schema* no MongoDB, que dá, parte da performance já começa piorar, mesmo no modelo de documento. Para ter mais performance ele abre mão de alguma coisa. Se isso importa para seu problema, faça o mesmo no SQL.

Se você desligar a durabilidade, que dá, seja no SQL, seja no MongoDB, fica um avião. Algumas comparações divulgadas fazem isso, desligam em um e não no outro, **comparam coisas muito distintas**.

A maioria das pessoas repetem o que ouviram dizer. Outras agem de má fé sabendo que estão induzindo os outros a erro com informação falsa, mas são mais raros, a maioria o faz por ingenuidade e fanatismo.

Mesmo que no passado, quando o termo NoSQL e essa geração de DBs surgiram, tivesse algum ganho, os concorrentes se mexeriam e resolveriam problemas de performance. Modelos que se denominam NoSQL hoje em dia existem até antes do modelo relacional, não é algo moderno, só termo é e criado para ajudar vender esses novos produtos.

Assim como aconteceu no processo da última década. O NoSQL trouxe algumas *features* que o SQL não tinha, mas hoje quase todos SGDBRs possuem quase tudo o que o MongoDB permite (outros NoSQL também, pelo menos em alguns produtos), ainda que não da forma mais fácil, assim como é muito difícil fazer certas coisas com MongoDB, em alguns casos de forma muito lenta. E adivinha? Muitas dessas coisas são as que mais são necessárias para a maioria das aplicações.

Se o modelo de documento cai como uma luva para seu problema, então pode ser que tenha algum ganho, nada extraordinário, sem mágica. Mas isso pode depender de alguns fatores.

## Por baixo dos panos

Não acredite em ninguém que se diz especialista em bancos de dados e não saiba como eles funcionam por baixo dos panos. E se ela souber e continuar afirmando que um é claramente mais rápido que o outro, ela cai no grupo da má fé, já citado.

Eu não acompanho tudo o que se faz com MongoDB e não posso dar detalhes de como ele opera agora, mas sei que há um bom tempo ele usa um *engine* de *storage* chamado WiredTiger, que eles compraram há alguns anos.

Ele tem dois sabores, um deles é baseado em estruturas **B Tree**, a mesma que quase todos os bancos de dados SQL usa. Não tem mágica, não tem como isso ser melhor.

[image: Diagrama com estrutura de árvore]

O WiredTiger tem um outro modo que no fundo é uma implementação bem diferente que usa estrutura **LSM Tree** que dá um ganho bem grande em algumas situações de escrita, já vi 10x, mas o mais comum é ser 2X, e muitos casos o ganho é menor, mínimo, nada ou é até negativo.

[image: Diagrama com LSM Tree]

Parece ótimo e confirma que aí é verdade ser mais rápido. Como eu disse, nem sei se ele pode ser usado de fato no MongoDB hoje em dia, conheço mais sobre o WiredTiger, mas vamos dizer que pode. Sendo usado realmente pode dar um ganho na escrita, pagando um preço alto na leitura. É muito mais comum o preço ser bem mais alto e ficar algumas vezes mais lento. Já vi mais de 100x em caso extremo, mas pode ter caso que até anula.

Ainda que não seja comum, nada impede que um DB relacional use LSM, especialmente os que podem trocar de *engine*, e de fato alguns oferecem isso mesmo que através de um *fork*. Use o [MyRocks](http://myrocks.io/) e veja escrita ser bem melhor que leitura.

LSM tem **amplificação de leitura** porque para ter certeza que está com dados atualizados precisa ler em vários lugares. É tão trágico que é comum que LSM seja comprimido por padrão para não ficar pior ainda. Já atualizar é bem simples, faz do jeito mais simples possível.

Se quiser comprimir dados em B Tree o ganho é extra, é só porque queria isso, então ele pode ficar ainda mais rápido, para escrita e leitura. Em certas situações, igual ao LSM que é a norma, afinal tem casos que o custo da compressão é maior que o ganho de acesso ao "disco", especialmente nos meios mais modernos como SSD e NvRAM (a compressão deve atrapalhar em quase todos os casos).

Já B Tree acessa os dados de forma muito simples e rápida, mas para escrever e balancear a árvore ela entra em **amplificação de escrita** e uma simples modificação pode realizar várias escritas.

Paradoxalmente, se praticamente não tiver escrita com LSM, a leitura pode ficar rápida. Mas aí o modelo adequado é outro.

#### O mais rápido

Já ouviu falar do formato `.dbf`? Ele é usado pelo dBase, Clipper, Harbour e outras variações chamadas xBase. Quer performance? Use ele. É relacional (pode ser usado de outras formas), não te dá muitas garantias, só algumas, do ACID basicamente só o D de verdade, desperdiça espaço como ninguém, mas é um avião para escrita e leitura.

Tudo é *tradeoff*.

## Qual é o melhor?

- Qual é o padrão de uso que sua aplicação faz? Escreve mais ou lê mais dados?
- O grosso do que você faz é em dados tabulares, ou documentos estanques?
- Os dados costumam estar relacionados entre si ou são independentes?
- Os dados são bem estruturados em sua maioria ou cada dado tem uma estrutura própria?
- Vai usar os dados de forma estruturada diferente da forma armazenada, como em relatórios por exemplo?
- O volume é monstruoso e precisa armazenar em muitos servidores?

Esses padrões é que farão você decidir por um ou outro, e em cada caso poderá ter mais performance pelo uso adequado.

É mais fácil desligar as garantias e modelo relacional do SQL do que ligar e relacionar no MongoDB. Se você tem algo híbrido provavelmente ainda se beneficiará mais, inclusive em desempenho, usando um SQL/relacional. Um NoSQL é ótimo se você tem um modelo puro que encaixa para aquele produto.

Não se esqueça que as pessoas costumam achar que seus problemas são maiores e mais complicados que realmente são. Todo mundo acha que terá escala do tipo Google quando na verdade até o SQLite atende ela.

## Então por que as pessoas adotam documento onde não deve e não fica trágico?

Também é verdade que a maioria das pessoas usam bancos de dados de forma muito básica, tanto que se usar o modelo errado não faz muita diferença. Só sentirá pelo erro em volumes muito grandes, que quase ninguém precisa.

#### Exemplo

"Todo mundo" diz que o padrão que este site aqui usa seria melhor em um NoSQL porque ele tem um monte de documentos. Mas ele usa o SQL Server e é considerado um dos sites mais eficientes que existe no mundo, bate em performance muitos outros menores que usam NoSQL e precisam de bem mais servidores, e não são conhecidos por responder muito rápido, como o SO é.

E adivinha? O grosso do que o SQL faz é escrita :) A leitura é feita mais por um NoSQL, o Redis, portanto não um banco de dados mesmo, e sim por um cache. O NoSQL não é usado para armazenar os dados, só para facilitar o acesso em algo tão requisitado.

Isso mostra como tem muita crença que não se sustenta na prática.

## Conclusão

Todo teste que mostrar NoSQL, MongoDB ou não, que mostre ganho significativo em relação ao SQL de qualquer fornecedor, de Oracle à SQLite, está **comparando coisas muito diferentes**, injustas, ou usando algum truque. Dá para "provar" o oposto também.

Já existe DBMS híbrido que armazena cada parte em um modelo para atender as demandas diversas da melhor forma, mas eles não são muito populares. Claro que existem desvantagens também, como tudo.

Os maiores especialistas em banco de dados adotam o modelo relacional, e se ele não encaixar bem vão para outros modelos. Quem adota primeiro outros modelos tem viés ou só sabe aquele modelo.

Eu traduzi respostas do Bill Karwin sobre o assunto:

- [Um RDBMS tradicional, como o PostgreSQL, pode ser projetado para ter desempenho de leitura/gravação semelhante a um banco de dados NoSQL, como o Cassandra?](https://pt.quora.com/Um-RDBMS-tradicional-como-o-PostgreSQL-pode-ser-projetado-para-ter-desempenho-de-leitura-grava%C3%A7%C3%A3o-semelhante-a-um-banco-de-dados-NoSQL-como-o-Cassandra/answer/Antonio-Maniero)
- [NoSQL é um absurdo?](https://pt.quora.com/NoSQL-%C3%A9-um-absurdo/answer/Antonio-Maniero)

E ainda:

- [Por que alguns desenvolvedores preferem SQL quando o NoSQL tem um esquema mais flexível?](https://pt.quora.com/Por-que-alguns-desenvolvedores-preferem-SQL-quando-o-NoSQL-tem-um-esquema-mais-flex%C3%ADvel/answer/Antonio-Maniero)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Quem negativou precisa me dizer o que tem de errado pra eu corrigir.

Comment: Acho que foi porque esqueceu de mencionar que MongoDB é mais rápido pra dar dor de cabeça.

Comment: Pode ser, mas muitas vezes demora (ou seja, vai descobrir que escolheu mal no pior momento). Pode ser que seja alguém que gosta de me negativar. Pode ter sido só pontual.